# How to display results after console.log is complete from smart contract

Tags: html, reactjs, user-interface, smartcontracts

```
    const init = async()=>{

      console.log("waiting for Fill1 method to complete");
      const result1 = await contract.methods.Fill1("Mathematics", "77", "Physics", "80", "Chemistry", "30").send({from accounts[0]});
      console.log("Fill1 completed);
      console.log("Events from Fill1);
      console.log(result1.events);
}
return (
<button onClick = {init} type "button">Display Information</button>
);
```

This code above renders the information from the smart contract onto the console correctly but I am unable to find a way of now displaying it in the UI using react. I don't know if I should be using `React.render()` or if there is some other way. I am new to React so any assistance would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

is this all of the code? do you have like a onChange() or handleTask method?

Comment: This is all the code. I don't have a handleTask or onChange method

Comment: [link to examples](https://github.com/DevMountain/react-drills) i find this repo has good examples that should be able to fix your problem